# How to load a form when a SQL entry is made

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

first time asking a question here!

I'm designing a notification bar for my application, so I'm using a timer to check the database every 30 seconds for a new entry. But I'm a bit stuck on how you would go about loading the form (notification bar) when an entry is made by another user. Any help is appreciated!

This is my code below to connect and select the data from the server.

```
    Public Sub Form10_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim RFT_Connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("connectionstring")
    Dim Not_DA As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SQL_RFT_Log INNER JOIN Departments ON Departments.ID = Returned_From_Value
            INNER JOIN Departments As DeptTemp ON DeptTemp.ID = Returned_To_Value
            INNER JOIN Reasons ON Reasons.Reason_ID = SQL_RFT_Log.Return_Reason_Value
            INNER JOIN Prod ON Prod.ID = SQL_RFT_Log.Product_Value
            INNER JOIN Parts ON Parts.ID = SQL_RFT_Log.Part_Value
            INNER JOIN UserDepartment ON UserDepartment.Department_ID = SQL_RFT_Log.Returned_To_Value
            LEFT JOIN Suppliers on Suppliers.SupID = SQL_RFT_Log.Supplier
            WHERE Seen IS NULL", RFT_Connection)
    Dim Temp_Not_DS As New DataSet

    RFT_Connection.Open()
    Not_DA.Fill(Temp_Not_DS, "Not_DT")

    NotLB.Text = "You have " & Temp_Not_DS.Tables("Not_DT").Rows.Count.ToString & " Notifications!"

    If Temp_Not_DS.Tables("Not_DT").Rows.Count.ToString = 0 Then

        ViewBTN.Enabled = False

    End If

    RFT_Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you include the code you have worked so far so we can get more details on what you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks @CrushSundae I've posted the code that will connect it to the sql database. Every time an entry is made to that data base i want the form to load

Comment: 1) You should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - and set it as the default for VB.NET projects. 2) How do you detect that an entry has been made? 3) You don't need to open and close `RFT_Connection` because `.Fill` will do that for you, but you do need to `RFT_Connection.Dispose()` afterwards to free up unmanaged resources.

Comment: `Temp_Not_DS.Tables("Not_DT").Rows.Count.ToString = 0`.. .`ToString` will produce a `String` and your comparing it to an `Integer`.. Remove `.ToString`.

Comment: Another is you need to stop the timer when a notification has been prompted. Otherwise, it will always show as your timer is still running.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Obviously I am a novice so I'm just getting used to vb.net